# Materializecss table with defined height and vertical scroll

Tags: angularjs, scroll, material-design, materialize

I need a table with defined height or maxHeight and vertical scroll. But, the materializecssTable seems to be ignoring the height css property. 
Has anyone done it before?
Can any one help me?